# Oracle Apex send email

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-apex

I was using utl_smtp to send email from my oracle Apex Application and every thing was working fine, after my mail server updating to TLS 1.2 my Oracle Package doesnt work any more !!!
I've tested adding Wallet and other solutions but it doesnt work!
I get different errors like: Service unavailable or Certificate validation failed!!
any one knows how should I solve it? or is there any mail provider, who doesnt need any TLS certification?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY send_email
        IS


   -- constants

   c_username VARCHAR2 (50) := 'my_sender';
   c_password VARCHAR2 (50) := 'my_password';


   the_connection UTL_SMTP.connection;

   -- Functions
    FUNCTION build_address_string (p_string IN VARCHAR2, p_rcps IN VARCHAR2, p_rcps_names IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

        i INTEGER;
        v_recipients VARCHAR2 (5000);
        v_reply UTL_SMTP.reply;
      
      
    BEGIN

        v_recipients := p_string ||  p_rcps ;
        
        v_reply := UTL_SMTP.rcpt (the_connection, p_rcps );

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| 'UTL_SMTP.rcpt p_recipient');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_recipients: '|| v_recipients);

        RETURN v_recipients;
    END;

       -- procedures
       --
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PROCEDURE send_email (p_to_rcps IN VARCHAR2, p_to_rcps_names IN VARCHAR2, p_cc_rcps IN VARCHAR2,
      p_cc_rcps_names IN VARCHAR2, p_subject IN VARCHAR2, p_message_body IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
   
        i INTEGER;
        v_adr_to VARCHAR2 (5000);
        v_adr_cc VARCHAR2 (5000);
        v_host_name VARCHAR2 (65);
        v_reply UTL_SMTP.reply;
        v_replies UTL_SMTP.replies;
        v_smtp_port NUMBER;
        v_smtp_server VARCHAR2 (100);
        v_smtp_sender VARCHAR2 (100);
        v_smtp_user VARCHAR2 (100);

    BEGIN

        v_host_name := 'the host name';
        v_smtp_server := 'smtp server name';
        v_smtp_port := 25;
        v_smtp_sender := 'email sender';
        v_smtp_user := 'email user';
      
      
        v_reply := UTL_SMTP.open_connection (v_smtp_server, v_smtp_port, the_connection);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' open connection reply');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);

        v_replies := UTL_SMTP.ehlo (the_connection, v_smtp_server);

        i := v_replies.FIRST;

        WHILE (i IS NOT NULL)
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'count i '|| i|| ' ehlo replies');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply '|| v_replies (i).code);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply '|| v_replies (i).text);

            i := v_replies.NEXT (i);
        END LOOP;


        IF (v_smtp_user != 'ANONYMOUS')
        THEN
        
            -- BEGIN AUTHENTICATION
            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.command (the_connection, 'AUTH LOGIN'); -- should receive a 334 response, prompting for username

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' AUTH LOGIN');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);

            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.command (the_connection, UTL_ENCODE.text_encode (c_username, 'WE8ISO8859P1', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64)); -- should receive a 334 response, prompting for password

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' username reply');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);

            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.command (the_connection, UTL_ENCODE.text_encode (c_password, 'WE8ISO8859P1', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64)); -- should receive a 235 response, you are authenticated

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' pwd reply');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);
            -- END AUTHENTICATION
        ELSE
            v_reply.code := 235;
        END IF;

        IF (v_reply.code = 235)
        THEN
            -- Check the sender
            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.mail (the_connection, v_smtp_sender);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' UTL_SMTP.mail sender');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);

            -- Creating Adsresses
            v_adr_to := build_address_string ('To: ', p_to_rcps, p_to_rcps_names);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_adr_to: '|| v_adr_to);

            v_adr_cc := build_address_string ('Cc: ', p_cc_rcps, p_cc_rcps_names);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_adr_cc: '|| v_adr_cc);

            -- Writing the data
            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.open_data (the_connection);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' UTL_SMTP.open_data ');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);


            UTL_SMTP.write_data(the_connection, 'From: ' || v_host_name || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.write_data(the_connection, 'Subject: ' || NVL (p_subject, '(no subject)') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            --UTL_SMTP.write_data(the_connection, 'Reply-To: ' || v_adr_to || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.write_data(the_connection, v_adr_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.write_data(the_connection, v_adr_cc || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.write_data (the_connection, '' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.write_data(the_connection, p_message_body || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

            -- sending email and closing the connection
            UTL_SMTP.close_data (the_connection);

            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.quit (the_connection);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' UTL_SMTP.quit');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);

        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'authentication failure ');

            v_reply := UTL_SMTP.quit (the_connection);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.code: '|| v_reply.code|| ' UTL_SMTP.quit');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'v_reply.text: '|| v_reply.text);
        END IF;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_SMTP.transient_error OR UTL_SMTP.permanent_error
        THEN
            BEGIN
                UTL_SMTP.quit (the_connection);

            EXCEPTION
                WHEN UTL_SMTP.transient_error OR UTL_SMTP.permanent_error
                THEN
                    RAISE;
            -- have a connection to the server. The quit call will
            -- raise an exception that we can ignore.
            END;

            raise_application_error (-20000, 'Failed to send mail due to the following error: ' || SQLERRM);
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            RAISE;
    END send_email;


    
    END send_email;
    /
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `apex_mail` built-in package. Here's an example of a procedure that sends an "ordinary" mail or - if you also pass attachment name and `CLOB` parameter values - sends mail with an attachment.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_send_mail (i_from         IN VARCHAR2,
                              i_to           IN VARCHAR2,
                              i_cc           IN VARCHAR2,
                              i_bcc          IN VARCHAR2,
                              i_id_email     IN NUMBER,
                              i_subject      IN VARCHAR2,
                              i_text_msg     IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                              i_attach_name  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                              i_attach_mime  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                              i_attach_clob  IN CLOB DEFAULT NULL)
IS
   l_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   l_id :=
      apex_mail.send (p_from       => i_from,
                      p_to         => i_to,
                      p_cc         => i_cc,
                      p_bcc        => i_bcc,
                      p_replyto    => NULL,
                      p_subj       => i_subject,
                      p_body       => i_text_msg,
                      p_body_html  => i_text_msg);

   IF     i_attach_name IS NOT NULL
      AND i_attach_clob IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      apex_mail.add_attachment (p_mail_id     => l_id,
                                p_filename    => i_attach_name,
                                p_mime_type   => i_attach_mime,
                                p_attachment  => i_attach_clob);
   END IF;
END p_send_mail;
```

---

If you need something really simple, just call

```
apex_mail.send (p_from  => i_from,
                p_to    => i_to,
                p_subj  => i_subject,
                p_body  => i_text_msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you can use Apex_mail inbuild service for easy and effective method.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI343

Answer (score 1):

[image: Oracle apex have a simple mail send option without p]

Oracle apex have a simple mail-send option without a program unit.